# Hibernate - Delete Query From @ManyToMany

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two objects: Event and User. Both have a reference to one another:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Event")
public class Event implements Serializable {

    //some fields

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "Event_User",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false, updatable = false), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false))
    List<User> attendingUsers = new ArrayList<User>();

    //Getters and Setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable {
    //Attributes

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "attendingUsers")
    private List<Event> attendingEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Okay, now I have the situation where I want users to be able to unattend Events. I've tried several things so far, but it looks like only a query is going to work. The reason why I want to use a query is: I cannot use `Hibernate.initialize(event.getAttendingUsers())` and so `event.getAttendingUsers().clean()` won't do it.

My query looks like this so far:

```
@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
@Service("eventService")
public class EventService implements IEventService {

        public void unattend(Event e, User u){
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                "SELECT u FROM User AS u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.attendingEvents AS ae WHERE ae.id = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", e.getId());
        List<User> attendingUsers = (List<User>)query.list();

        if(attendingUsers.contains(u)){
            Query delete = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                    "DELETE FROM u.attendingEvents AS ae WHERE ae.id = :event_id"
                    );
            delete.setParameter("event_id", e.getId());
            delete.executeUpdate();

            attendingUsers.remove(u);
            e.setAttendingUsers(attendingUsers);
            update(e);
        }
}
```

However, it results in an `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: u.attendingEvents is not mapped [DELETE FROM u.attendingEvents AS ae WHERE ae.id = :event_id]` Exception. Yet I don't know how to map it without deleting the event (I only want to delete the entries from the join table: event_user. If I try to delete from event_user directly I also get the same exception, that `event_user is not mapped`.

Any ideas how I could solve this problem?

*EDIT*: When I try to use the 'simple' way I end up like this:

`08.01.2014 17:03:02 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/tripitude] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ac.tuwien.ase08.tripitude.entity.Event.attendingUsers, could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ac.tuwien.ase08.tripitude.entity.Event.attendingUsers, could not initialize proxy - no Session`

My code is:

```
@Transactional
public void unattend(Event e, User u){
        try{
            Hibernate.initialize(e.getAttendingUsers());
        } catch(Exception ex){}

        e.getAttendingUsers().remove(u);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any query. All you need to do is to remove the user from the list of uses of the event you want to unattend. To make your object graph coherent, you should also remove the event from the events of the user, but Hibernate won't care about it because it's the inverse side of the association:

```
public void unattend(Event e, User u){
    // mandatory:
    e.getUsers().remove(u);
    // optional:
    u.getEvents().remove(e);
}
```

The above assumes `u` and `e` are attached entities, of course. If they're not, then, in a transaction, start by getting them by ID from the database, and call the above method with the entities returned.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping it was that easy, however, it won't work for me. If I only try to access the attending users with `e.getAttendingUsers()` I get a NullPointerException. But I know that I need to initialize them first, see my edit for what happens please :/

Comment: As I said in my answer: don't work on objects coming from I don't know where. Get the event by ID from the database using session.find(), get the user by ID from the database using session.find(), then work with these two attached entities. All this inside a transactional service.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot :) I had to find both event and user by id first and then `Hibernate.initialize(e.getAttendingUsers)` AND `Hibernate.initialize(u.getAttendingEvents)`. After that I was able to delete :)

Comment: The initialize is useless. Calling remove() on the returned list will automatically initialize it.